# Why can't I get my Nvidia 560 Ti to work with dual monitors?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Installation method:

- Downloaded 11.10 iso and installed to USB stick with no persistent area,
- Ran Ubuntu from the USB stick to check hardware compatability,
- Used the desktop icon to run installer from within running Ubuntu,
- Checked the box to download updates while installing,
- Checked the box to allow 3rd party stuff while installing.

Hardware (see end of post), i7, GeForce GFX 560 Ti.

Launching from USB, Ubuntu detected both monitors and I was able to use "Displays" to configure my monitors. However, I noted that it was running in "standard" experience (unity2d). Both monitors were correctly identified by "Displays".

After booting the new install from HD, only one monitor is detected. nVidia drivers were already enabled from within Jockey. Using sudo nvidia-settings, after much experimentation I was able to get both displays working by using "TwinView" (which seems wrong).

Displays shows a single 3200x1080 display of "Unknown",
"Detect Displays" does nothing,

System Info shows "Graphics Unknown" and "Experience Standard"

Is there some way to get it to behave the same way that the "Live" Ubuntu ran (correctly detecting two monitors and allowing me to configure them directly without going thru the control panel) and is there a way to get Unity 3D to run on this card?

- Oliver

Hardware:

```
osmith@quaver:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub to ESI Port (rev 12)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 12)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 12)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev 12)
00:14.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub System Management Registers (rev 12)
00:14.1 PIC: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub GPIO and Scratch Pad Registers (rev 12)
00:14.2 PIC: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub Control Status and RAS Registers (rev 12)
00:14.3 PIC: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub Throttle Registers (rev 12)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
00:1a.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 3
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 90)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JIR (ICH10R) LPC Interface Controller
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SATA AHCI Controller
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti] (rev a1)
02:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation Device 0e0c (rev a1)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the third party drivers. I had the same issue and have seen other posts on the forum as well.

Comment: Can you link to those posts on the forum?

Comment: Deactivated nVidia drivers in jockey, still no joy: Displays still only sees one "unknown" display and jockey seems to think there is a different version of the second driver installed.

Comment: See: http://www.kfs.org/oliver/images/first.jpg http://www.kfs.org/oliver/images/second.jpg and http://www.kfs.org/oliver/images/displays.jpg